# send message according to ip asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip

I have a website containing users. every user have a specific ip ... i want to add some feature to my website to talk with this users by ip according to there country and maybe able to send message to stranger and pop a div containing my message .... but i don't know how to do it

or what technique should i use ... so if u can help me and give me the idea or some link or code to be able to add this feature .
note: i am useing asp.net with c# code behind and i want it as soon as possible because within two days i should start working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following to get IP address.

`string ipaddress = Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();`

Then, let's say you have JS function to show pop message based on IP. You can invoke that JS function from aspx code behind using following.

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scrpt",string.Format("<script>alert('Your ip {0}');</script>",ipaddress));`

**Note:** I have used `alert` to just show current IP addres.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now. I thing about Geolocation in HTML5. It is in W3Schools: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)
Or an API of a geolocation service.

Answer (score 0):

[SignalR](http://asp.net/signalr) is very good for chat or any Real-Time Application. It's very easy to use. see this [Video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B416)